# Outlook 2010 won't automatically update shared folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I'm having a problem with an Outlook 2010 client.  I have added an additional mailbox to an Exchange account. This is the second of two additional mailboxes; the first additional mailbox works fine and I can browse and read email in the box.  However the second mailbox shows only the folder with no mail, until I click Send / Receive -> Update Folders, then it downloads  fine and I can read the mail.  When I turn off shared folder caching it works fine.

I've also tried a new mail profile but the same thing happens with the new mail profile.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982697) apply to your case ?

Comment: If you turn off caching, does it work as expected?

Comment: @techie007 yes it will work online just fine just not in cached mode